# How to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors for $N\times N$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to write a Java code that calculates both eigenvalues and eigenvectors for any given $N\times N$ matrix. I have to find all $λ$ such that $|A−λI|=0$. When $N = 2,3,4$ you can find $λ$ pretty easily with predetermined math formulas. However, when N gets bigger than $4$, you will have to solve the high-degree polynomial equation. So, I then read about solving an $N$-degree polynomial equation in general, but there seemed to be no clear-cut ways to solve it. What's your advice/opinion? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323591/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-large-matrix) can help.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome, Jose.

Comment: @Gary, thanks I checked them.